# User input determining the length of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make the code, take the input from the user in list1, and depending on how long they make list1, will determine the length of the list2. Then it will call the method and compare the two strings and see if they are identical or not.

I know that my code limits both list1 and list2 to only 6 ints, but that is because I don't know how to do it the other way yet, and I was wondering if you guys can help?

```
//A program that prompts the user to enter two list of integers
//and displays whether the two are identical

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class IdenticalArrays {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Initialize Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Start loop
    while (true) {
      //Arrays
      int[] list1 = new int[6];
      int[] list2 = new int[6];

      //User input
      System.out.println("Enter list1: ");
      for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++)
        list1[i] = input.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter list2: ");
      for (int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++)
        list2[i] = input.nextInt();

      //Call method
      if (equals(list1, list2))
        System.out.println("Two lists are identical");
      else
        System.out.println("Two list are not identical");

      //Continuation of loop
      System.out.println("Do you want to continue (Y/N)?");
      String s = input.nextLine();
      s = input.nextLine();
      s = s.toLowerCase();
      if (s.charAt(0) == 'n')
        break;
    }

  }
  public static boolean equals(int[] list1, int[] list2) {
    if (list1.length == list2.length) {
      Arrays.sort(list1);
      Arrays.sort(list2);
    } else
      return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
      if (list1[i] != list2[i])
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: What about arraylist? That allows you change the size all you want

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of choices. One, you could ask the user up front how many items they want to enter and then use that answer to set both array lengths from the start. Another, you could use a dynamic structure like a List to accept the data, and then create an array from the List and proceed as before. Or you could just make a REALLY BIG array and hope the user gets bored before they get to the end of it. (this is not the right way...)

However, you don't actually need the second list, since you can just compare each input from the user to the appropriate entry in the initial input set.